# Drawing an arc within two defined points in C graphics

Tags: geometry

I would like to know whether there is any mathematical equation to draw an arc in c within the defined points using mathematical equations.

Right know I'm doing an trial and error method to fit an arc within the defined points using [graphics.h](http://1drv.ms/1GACf6r) arc function.This is a time consuming process and I would like to know whether the distance `d` between two points can be related to the start angle,end angle and the radius as shown in the figure.

Arc function is `void arc(int x, int y, int stangle, int endangle, int radius);`. 
[image: Arc drawn within two points]

Comment: How are a, b, c, d related to the location of the arc?  Are the two lines always vertical?  How long are the lines?

Comment: @Tpofofn:I would like to know whether you can draw an arc between two points (a,b) and (c,d) if we find the start angle,end angle and radius using mathematical equations.Is there any mathematical equation?